# How to map control key to a specific angle or orientation?

Tags: 3d, three.js, babylonjs

At the moment, I basically have built out a large hash table of various angles and what direction they map to, if the user would press right, up, down, left. This is needed, in my case, as I have a collection of geometries that when the user presses right, they all go right, and when left, they all go left ...

However, when the scene containing these is rotated anything other than its original state, these controls need to be updated/reversed/etc. That is, if you're looking at the scene from behind, pressing left now has the objects all going right, etc.

I was trying to see if there is a simpler way of applying matrix transformations instead of hard coding a large hash table mapping various scene angles to keys.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not clear. I have the scene and the objects rotating, however, the controls get messed up, because if the scene is now reversed, your lefts become your right, etc... I was hoping of a simpler way of mapping controls to a direction rather than building a large if/else or object map, where I would map a scene rotation angle to a direction of the keys. For example: if scene.rotation === 0, right = x but if scene.rotation === Math.PI, right = -x, etc... this is a simple example of what I'm going for, but I have it for all directions

Answer (score 0):

You can use a displacement vector (of a set of such vectors, each for desired movement direction) and just rotate it with a camera or, if your camera is stationary and the scene is rotated, rotate displacements in direction **opposite** to direction of the scene rotation (i.e., if you rotate the scene clockwise around x-axis, rotate the displacement vectors around the same axis counterclockwise by the same angle). To put more formally, you should apple rotation matrix inverse of the rotation of the scene.

Old answer:

> If I've understood your question correctly, you're after some way to
>   view your scene from different angled using a keyboard. Well, one can
>   get really imaginative with ways to do that, but one of, I think, most
>   conventional ways to do that is to rotate the scene while
>   corresponding key's pressed. For example, while a left key is pressed,
>   in every frame add (or subtract) a constant value (that would be the
>   rotation speed) to (from) scene rotation around a given axis:
>
> ```
> var speed = 0;
>
> document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
>     switch (e.keyCode) {
>         case 37: // left arrow
>             speed = -0.1;
>             break;
>         case 39: // right arrow
>             speed = 0.1;
>             break;
>     }
> });
> document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
>     speed = 0;
> });
>
> function update () {
>     scene.rotateX(speed);
>     renderer.render(scene, camera);
>     requestAnimationFrame(update);
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not clear. I have the scene and the objects rotating, however, the controls get messed up, because if the scene is now reversed, your lefts become your right, etc... I was hoping of a simpler way of mapping controls to a direction rather than building a large if/else or object map, where I would map a scene rotation angle to a direction of the keys.

For example: if scene.rotation === 0, right = x but if scene.rotation === Math.PI, right = -x, etc... this is a simple example of what I'm going for, but I have it for all directions

Comment: @Detuned Am I right to say that you want to link, say, direction of movement of an object to the camera? So when you press right key, the object would always go right on the screen.

Comment: By any chance, do you have a working example? That would be SUPER helpful as I haven't found anything else on the web.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. If something unclear about the idea, ask a question here in the comments, I'd be happy to help you to understand it.